# Send NFC tag in Android if app isn't open?

Tags: android, tags, nfc

It's possible to send any string by NFC in Android if i dont have any application open to make it?

Imagine you pass the smartphone in passive mode on a reader NFC. Can reader receveive any data if i dont have a application on the smartphone side to send it?

Comment: You mean to use the smartphone like an NFC card?

Comment: yes, exactly but without have application in foreground. it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Card emulation it's not yet public in the sdk. Read [here](http://blog.sarion.jp/cbytes/2011/05/the-state-of-nfc-in-android.html) paragraph Card Emulation, but maybe there is a way as you can read in the blog.

Answer (score 4):

In short, no, at least not through SDK API's.

There are no NFC Card Emulation SDK API's.

Peer-to-peer would also work, but these API's only allow a foreground Activity to send a message. This is by design.

The basic reason is to keep privacy simple for the user, we talk about this in more detail in our "How to NFC" talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49L7z3rxz4Q